# how to render multiple collections data to page in node js from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am having problems rendering multiple collection to page.I have done a lot of research but getting an error like Failed to look up view in views directory
my code is following

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
} else {
db.collection('book', function(err, collection1) {
collection1.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
db.collection('category', function(err, collection) {
collection.find().toArray(function(err, citems) {
res.send('pages/home', {title:'Express',itm:items,citm:citems});
});
});
});
});
 }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your view location, it's cannot be found by path `pages/home`

Try to debug this first and don't think about mongodb now. But if you want to debug mongodb queries - just log into console your `items` and `citems`

Comment: i am getting items and citems afer printing them in console but when i pass them in page to render values i get page views look up error

Comment: console.log(items,citems)
         //     res.render('./pages/home', { title: 'Express',itm:items,citm:citems}); it works if i uncomment it but not able to render it to page

Comment: show your files structure tree and where you initialize view engine for express. Something with your pathes

Comment: i have attached an image showing file structure. i have used ejs engine to show views templates

Comment: ok, @NarendraSharma, the problem is with view named 'error', cause your request generatin error and express trying to lookup 'error.ejs'. Maybe problem inside your home.ejs structure or code. Try to delete all content from home.ejs and look at the backend logs, if it's generating error or not

Answer (score 1):

In app.js you can set the views to view like this:

```
app.set('views', [__dirname + 'views', __dirname + 'views/pages']);
```

and your response to:

```
res.render('home',{title:'Express',itm:items,citm:citems});
```

Comment: once try creating error.ejs file in your views directory instead or error.jade.

Comment: i tried creating error.ejs but still getting the same error msg

Answer (score 0):

try this (I am assuming you are using express.js and jade)

res.render('./pages/home', {title:'Express',itm:items,citm:citems});

Comment: no luck big bro . i am still getting an error it works great by doing so but not when uncommenting render page             console.log(items,citems)
         //     res.render('./pages/home', { title: 'Express',itm:items,citm:citems});

Answer (score 0):

In app.js, please add the following piece of code,

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Hope this helps, Thanks..!